# full caption in Image captioning using keras approach in python

Tags: python, image, keras, caption

I have tried Image captioning using keras approach , I only get the next word in the sequence, how do I get the full caption of the images ?
I got the next word value 
like the output in res is (5,5)(two images in test) which is number associated with the words.

here is my code.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, ZeroPadding2D
from keras.optimizers import SGD, Adadelta, Adagrad
from keras.utils import np_utils, generic_utils
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.layers.advanced_activations import PReLU, LeakyReLU
from keras.layers import Embedding,GRU,TimeDistributed,RepeatVector,Merge
from keras.preprocessing.text import one_hot
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
import cv2
import numpy as np
from keras import backend as K 
K.set_image_dim_ordering('th')

max_caption_len = 15
vocab_size = 20
def VGG_16(weights_path=None):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1),input_shape=(3,224,224)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2),dim_ordering='th'))

    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2),dim_ordering='th'))

    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2),dim_ordering='th'))

    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2),dim_ordering='th'))

    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2),dim_ordering='th'))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(1000, activation='softmax'))

    if weights_path:
        model.load_weights(weights_path)

    return model
print "VGG loading"
image_model = VGG_16('vgg16_weights_th_dim_ordering_th_kernels.h5')
image_model.trainable = False
print "VGG loaded"
# let's load the weights from a save file.
# image_model.load_weights('weight_file.h5')

# next, let's define a RNN model that encodes sequences of words
# into sequences of 128-dimensional word vectors.
print "Text model loading"
language_model = Sequential()
language_model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, 256, input_length=max_caption_len))
language_model.add(GRU(units=128, return_sequences=True))
language_model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(128)))
print "Text model loaded"
# let's repeat the image vector to turn it into a sequence.
print "Repeat model loading"
image_model.add(RepeatVector(max_caption_len))
print "Repeat model loaded"
# the output of both models will be tensors of shape (samples, max_caption_len, 128).
# let's concatenate these 2 vector sequences.
print "Merging"
model = Sequential()
model.add(Merge([image_model, language_model], mode='concat', concat_axis=-1))
# let's encode this vector sequence into a single vector
model.add(GRU(256, return_sequences=False))
# which will be used to compute a probability
# distribution over what the next word in the caption should be!
model.add(Dense(vocab_size))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop')
print "Merged"
# "images" is a numpy float array of shape (nb_samples, nb_channels=3, width, height).
# "captions" is a numpy integer array of shape (nb_samples, max_caption_len)
# containing word index sequences representing partial captions.
# "next_words" is a numpy float array of shape (nb_samples, vocab_size)
# containing a categorical encoding (0s and 1s) of the next word in the corresponding
# partial caption.
print "Data preprocessig"
Texts = ["START No MP seen END",
        "START No MP seen END",
        "START No abnormality seen END",
        "START No abnormality seen END",
        "START Overall Finding suggest possiblity of fungal lesion END"]

Images = ['Images/General Report_1864_b135a.jpg',
          'Images/General Report_1623_f3bee.jpg',
          'Images/General Report_3678_02bbc0.jpg',
          'Images/General Report_3678_56949.jpg',
          'Images/General Report_3998_21c27.jpg']
images = []
for image in Images:
    img = cv2.imread(image)
    img.resize((3,224,224))
    images.append(img)
images = np.asarray(images)

words = [txt.split() for txt in Texts]
unique = []
for word in words:
    unique.extend(word)
unique = list(set(unique))
word_index = {}
index_word = {}
for i,word in enumerate(unique):
    word_index[word] = i
    index_word[i] = word

partial_captions = []
for text in Texts:
    one = [word_index[txt] for txt in text.split()]
    partial_captions.append(one)

partial_captions = sequence.pad_sequences(partial_captions, maxlen=max_caption_len,padding='post')
next_words = np.zeros((5,vocab_size))
for i,text in enumerate(Texts):
    text = text.split()
    x = [word_index[txt] for txt in text]
    x = np.asarray(x)
    next_words[i,x] = 1

print "Data preprocessing done"
# The structure is as follows:
#(image, partial_caption)->(next_words)
#(image, "word1 word2")->("word3")    
model.fit([images, partial_captions], next_words, batch_size=1, nb_epoch=5)

# testing
Test_images=['testing Images/General Report_2361_e5399.jpg', 
             'testing Images/General Report_2660_04a446.jpg']
test_texts= ["START No MP seen END",
             "START No intra/axial collections seen END"]
test_images=[]
for i in Test_images:
    im=cv2.imread(i)
    im.resize((3,224,224))
    test_images.append(im)
test_images = np.asarray(test_images)
test_words = [txt.split() for txt in test_texts]
unique = []
for word in test_words:
    unique.extend(word)
unique = list(set(unique))
test_word_index = {}
test_index_word = {}
for i,word in enumerate(unique):
    test_word_index[word] = i
    test_index_word[i] = word

test_partial_captions = []
for text in test_texts:
    one = [test_word_index[txt] for txt in text.split()]
    test_partial_captions.append(one)

test_partial_captions = sequence.pad_sequences(partial_captions, maxlen=max_caption_len,padding='post')
test_next_words = np.zeros((5,vocab_size))
for i,text in enumerate(test_texts):
    text = text.split()
    x = [test_word_index[txt] for txt in text]
    x = np.asarray(x)
    test_next_words[i,x] = 1

res=model.predict_classes([test_images,test_partial_captions])
print res
```

Comment: Can anyone know the answer ? need some clarifications in questions ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `model.predict_classes`, you can use `model.predict`. This will return the softmax probabilities of next words for the vocab_size that you have given in the next_words shape. After getting the softmax probabilities, you can get more words from it.